# How to impute/replace missing values in a pandas DataFrame with a sequence of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For example, suppose I have this DataFrame:

```
Weights = pd.DataFrame({'Weight': [46, np.nan, 67, 62, np.nan, np.nan, 88, np.nan, 55, np.nan]})
Weights

    Weight
0   46.0
1   NaN
2   67.0
3   62.0
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   88.0
7   NaN
8   55.0
9   NaN
```

And I would like to replace/impute the NaN values with the following sequence of values:

```
replace = np.random.randint(45,90, size=(5,))
replace
array([85, 79, 68, 72, 52])
```

Such that the resulting DateFrame looks like:

```
Weights

    Weight
0   46
1   85
2   67
3   62
4   79
5   68
6   88
7   72
8   55
9   52
```

What code do I need? Could this be done using standard python code, only pandas, or only scikit-learn?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``Weights.loc[Weights.Weight.isnull(), 'Weight'] = replace``

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out

```
weights.replace({np.nan:replace})
```